# jQuery `.val` reporting a value for a select, with no option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select that looks like this:

```
<select id   = "baz"
        name = "Baz"
        size = 1>
  <option value="A1"> foo</option>
  <option value="A2"> bar</option>
  ...etc
  <option value="A99"> bat</option>
</select>
```

I've pulled this code from Firebug (and edited it), as the options themselves are read from the server by a CGI `#include`.

The value of the select is eventually read by JavaScript as follows:

```
var $input_baz = $("#baz");
...
var baz_pl = $input_baz.val();
```

Problem: the select is in a hidden div, and no selections have been made, but `baz_pl` contains the value `A1`. Why is `.val()` returning the first entry when nothing has been selected, and is there a simple fix for this? The select appears in a popup, and I can add code to detect if the popup 'Ok' button has been clicked, but I'd rather do it properly if possible.

Comment: The first option is always selected by default. You could add a dummy value as first one. Like `<option value="-1">-- Please select --</option>`.

Comment: @FelixKling I think you should just post this as an answer :)

Comment: @Val: I was hoping there is a better way ;)

Comment: @FelixKling I suppose s/he can use `$('select [selected=selected]').text()` but I am not sure it's the best way but your suggestion is fine :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first option is always selected by default. You could add a dummy entry as first one, with a value that does not occur otherwise in the list.

For example:

```
<option value="-1">-- Please select --</option>
```

Comment: If I give `value=""` instead of `value="-1"` is there any problem?